# Lifespan chain and gear wheels on e-bike

Tags: maintenance, chain, gears, electric-bike

If is possible to give an indication of the  average lifespan of the chain and gear wheels of an E-bike? 
Assuming: Cycling in all weather conditions (commute); Western European climate (10% of time rainy, snow is rare). Average monthly temperature ranges from 0 to 20. No Cycling off road. Open chain/gear (no case).
Lifespan may be in km, or in years/months assuming about 3000 km/y.

Comment: The best thing to do is to get a quite inexpensive chain check tool and use it to keep an eye on chain lengthening.Usually they have two indicator 0.75% and 1% Once the chain has lengthened to .75% it is time for a change. The rear cogs life-span averages 2 chains. At 3000km/y a new chain in spring might be a good idea.

Comment: Where's the motor? A hub motor (front or rear) doesn't load the chain but other systems do. How hard you pedal is also an issue, as is the cleanliness of your roads, and how much salt it's exposed to from road treatment or seaside use.

Comment: We could only provide a guess.  Your best solution is to extrapolate from your own records saved over time.

Comment: @Criggie I know what my own record is, I am trying to establish if that is a normal record compared to others.

Comment: I'd expect 3000 km.  Perhaps 2000 km if you change the chain before 0.75 % wear.  Maybe 5000 km if you run the chain and cassette into the ground before changing them.  As low as 1000 km if you change the chain at 0.5% wear.  Decrease the number a bit if your roads have salt in the winter.  Increase if you store the bike inside in the warm/dry when its not being used and lower if its stored wet out in the rain and/or overnight.  Slightly longer if you wash and lube it regularly, and less again if you never clean it.     What's your number?

Comment: @Criggie So far, my wifes' chain and gear both had to be changed every year (after 3000). I was surprised at the gear, not so much the chain. My ordinary (not e-bike) lasts much longer.

Comment: @RHA So suppose you find out that your wear pattern is/isn't normal compared to others. Then what? You get hrough chains as fast as you get through them; knowing how often other people need to change their chains won't affect how often you need to change yours.

Answer (score 6):

It’s impossible to give an answer because chain and sprocket wear is dependent on load as well as distance. Stronger or heavier riders apply more force. Riding lots of hills will do the same.

The best approach is to get a chain wear gauge and record how long a chain lasts for you and your riding.

Conventional wisdom is 2 or 3 chains per cassette. Inspect the cassette when you replace the chain.

Answer (score 1):

Usual life span is around 3000km for regular use on an average road condition. We used to got a bad road and we noticed the lifespan improvement of the chains and gears since the road got fixed a couple of years ago.